# FFTW method fftw_cleanup() causing SIGABRT

Tags: c++, sigabrt, fftw

Good day ,
I am running a simulation program implemented in C++ which uses the FFTW libraries. 
The program was working fine for weeks. I now had to make some changes to a certain class A and now the program crashes at runtime with SIGABRT. I get no compiler warnings however(-Wall set).
The call stack of the Netbeans debugger looks like this

```
main -> ~class B -> class B::kill() -> fftw_cleanup() -> fftw_planner_destroy() -> 
??() -> ??() -> abort() -> raise() -> __kernel_vsyscall()
```

The peculiar thing is that the call stack does not list the class I changed, nor is it a member of class B or directly connected to it.

What exactly can cause fftw_cleanup() to fail (since the function takes no arguments)?

PS: I am using Netbeans 7.2.1 in a linux(opensuse) virtual machine.

Comment: Run it in valgrind to see if you are doing some dodgy memory stuff.

Comment: It looks like fftw_cleanup is destroying the plans that were made for fftw processing. I would look for the possibility that your changes corrupted the plans.

Comment: thanks so far, I think I'll first check what valgrind has to say. I didn't consider it so far because I didn't add any dynamic allocation with my changes...

Comment: once again Valgrind saves the day.